# Angular 2 - Style reusability with LESS and Webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, import, angular, less

How to reuse styles written in LESS files In Angular 2 app with Webpack?

Scenario:

I want to have a common.less file that contains the styles/style variables common for all the components. (example: some theme related variables)

Then, I want to import this common.less file in each of the component style's file, so that I don't have to rewrite these common styles/style variables there.

I am a Webpack user. When I tried this, I get the contents from common.less file getting copied in all the component-specific style files (which had `@import 'common.less'`), which is inefficient.

Need help in doing this properly. Appreciate your help on advance.

Answer (score 3):

When you load .less file into component's styles - each file is compiled separately and this is the normal behavior of LESS(SASS) compilers, when it renders there all real classes from imported file, you cannot change it.

So, only 1 proper way to avoid it - split your common.less file for few files, like app.less and variables.less. App styles just include into root component (usually smth like 'app.component' or whatever) and it contains all common classes.

And for all other component's less files just import only variables.less - file which contains ONLY variables and mixins - they will not be a part of final css, just real rendered classes and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try it out.

Comment: This is what i did. Didnt find any other way... :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `@import (reference) "common.less";`